# What are some good treatments to help a horse with strangles?

Tags: health, medicines, horses

It looks as though one of my horses has [strangles](http://agriculture.vic.gov.au/agriculture/pests-diseases-and-weeds/animal-diseases/horses/information-of-the-control-of-strangles-in-horses). I'm not looking for a substitution for veterinary care, I'm wanting to know of any home made remedies to relief the symptoms and help her cope with the illness.